# Is/are Subject Matter

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

> This works only when the number of edges of a pair of opposite
>   boundaries IS equal.

Or

> This works only when the number of edges of a pair of opposite
>   boundaries ARE equal.

Since subject is "the number", I think it should be IS. But "is equal" sounds bad since we're talking about "edges of a pair".

Comment: Neither statement is clear. How may edges can a boundary have? May be some context will help. Consider rewriting your question.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a pair of opposite boundaries. Each boundary has a number of edges.

Because you have two boundaries you have two numbers, so this is a plural, and you use ARE. But it also means your use of 'number' is wrong, it should be 'numbers'.

> ...the **numbers** of edges of a pair of opposite sides **are** equal.